# Cant seem to locate mysql databases

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I've tried to install mysql on OSX many a time and failed every time - I've tried installing it with macports, brew and somethign else, I can't remember. I ended up having someone who knows what they're doing getting it to work.

After it was installed, Rails happily obliged in creating databases for me. However, at this point, I need to run some arbitrary queries and upon running 'mysql' command in the terminal I see that the databases available through there are absolutely not what rails created.

Is it possible to have TWO versions of mysql installed or something? (Since I tried it so many times both with brew and macports) How would I check where Rails is saving databases and tables to and what location 'mysql' command in the terminal is trying to access?

I hope the question makes sense. I wasn't the one who ultimately got it to work so my knowledge of how it works is pretty weak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It definitely is possible to have more than one installation, with a different set of databases. I guess you'll have to ask the person who got it working for you.

Comment: What databases do you see? And what, exactly, did the knowledgeable person install? Just MySQL? A package to run apache too?

Comment: You can have as many installs as you want, with as many data store directories as you want, but it's unlikely you'd have more than one server running at a time, since they'd (by default) all be trying to bind to port 3306.

Comment: The person who helped me out is not available to help now. Is there a way I can check how many installations I have? I see two databases when I log on using terminal - information_schema and test. (I do believe the latter one was created by me when I was messing with the terminal mysql) so it's basically a virgin install. I have multiple rails apps that use mysql2 gem to create databases so there should be an install somewhere that has these databases, so I suppose it's just a matter of finding out where it is?

Comment: Do you mind posting the output of `which mysql` and `which mysqld` ?

Comment: `bundle exec rails dbconsole` will take you to the mysql console for the current app, while you are working out where and which mysql you are using.

Comment: Hey Richard I think you've 95% solved the issue. The remaining 5% is that that I get an error "Access denied to user ''@'localhost' to database 'myapp_development'. Is there a way to send args to dbconsole  to specify the username and\or password?

Comment: probably should put that as an answer when you respond :)

Comment: username and password would be whatever you specify in your development section of config/database.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you try to log usgin `mysql` command and then, `show databases;`.

   $ mysql -u username -p

   show databases;

It's not too common to have two installations. If your ruby programs are not specifying any specific hostname while connecting to database, then the command above should show exactly what your programs would be accessing too.

1. try to use netstat to check what ports are open and on LISTENING state

   $ netstat -na | grep LISTENING

After this, you can try to connect to any mysql host using the `-h hostname` option from the shell and check what databases exists.